# Как используется аннотация с параметрами в фильтрах REST?

Tags: java-ee, rest, аннотации

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с написанием аннотации с параметрами.
Например, требуется отфильтровать запрос в соответствии с ролью пользователя.
Вот так выглядит определение аннотации:

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Roles {
    Role[] roles();
}
```

Планируется её применять с классами или методами. Например:

```
@Roles(roles = {Role.USER})
public class UserResource {
    ...
}
```

или так

```
public class UserResource {

    @Roles(roles = {Role.ADMIN})
    @GET
    public Response getUser(){
        ...
    }

}
```

Фильтр выглядит следующим образом:

```
@Roles
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class RolesFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

    }
}
```

И вот проблема в том, что я не могу понять, как должен выглядеть фильтр и аннотация при нём. Ведь `@Roles` должна иметь параметры, но эти параметры определяются в аннотации над конкретным классом (`UserResource`) или методом (`getUser()`). Что должна содержать аннотация `@Roles` над фильтром, и как в методе `RolesFilter.filter` обратиться к методу аннотации `roles`?

Answer (score 0):

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey?rq=1) всё подробно расписано.
Если коротко, то вот так должна выглядеть аннотация:

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Roles {
    Role[] value() default {};
}
```

А вот фильтр:

```
@Roles
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class RolesFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Context
    HttpHeaders headers;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        Class<?> resourceClass = resourceInfo.getResourceClass();
        List<Role> classRoles = extractRoles(resourceClass);

        Method resourceMethod = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
        List<Role> methodRoles = extractRoles(resourceMethod);

        try {
            if (methodRoles.isEmpty()) {
                checkPermissions(classRoles);
            } else {
                checkPermissions(methodRoles);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            requestContext.abortWith(
                    Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build());
        }
    }

    private List<Role> extractRoles(AnnotatedElement annotatedElement) {
        if (annotatedElement == null) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            Roles roles = annotatedElement.getAnnotation(Roles.class);
            if (roles == null) {
                return new ArrayList<Role>();
            } else {
                Role[] allowedRoles = roles.value();
                return Arrays.asList(allowedRoles);
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkPermissions(List<Role> allowedRoles) throws Exception {
        Role userRole = Role.valueOf(headers.getHeaderString(UserToken.ROLE).toUpperCase());
        for (Role allowedRole : allowedRoles) {
            if (allowedRole == userRole)
                return;
        }
        throw new Exception("Не хватает прав для доступа");
    }
}
```

Здесь следует пояснить строку `Role userRole = Role.valueOf(headers.getHeaderString(UserToken.ROLE).toUpperCase());` из метода `checkPermissions`. На этапе аутентификации в другом фильтре (который отрабатывает раньше, так как у него `@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)`) из токена, который передаёт клиент, извлекается роль пользователя и добавляется в заголовок запроса. И теперь можно без проблем, используя `@Context HttpHeaders`, получить все заголовки и извлечь нужный.

Аннотирование класса выглядит так:

```
@Roles(Role.ADMIN)
public class UserResource {
   ...
}
```

или так (если нужно добавить несколько ролей)

```
 @Roles({Role.USER, Role.MODERATOR})
 public class UserResource {
    ...
 }
```